# Finding all elements of finite order in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G = \{g\in \mathbb Q\ | \ g\neq -3\}\subset \mathbb R,$ where $\mathbb Q$ denotes the set of rational numbers.  Define the multiplication $*$ over $G$ as follow.
$$ x*y := 2(x+3)(y+3) - 3,$$
for all $x, y\in G.$ It is easy to see that $(G, *)$ is a group.

Finding all elements of $G$ have finite order.  My solution is as follows.

Suppose $x\in G$ has finite order, then there is a smallest positive integer $k$ such that $x^k = e.$ Note that $x^k:=\underset{\text{ $k$ times}}{\underbrace{x*x*\cdots * x}}.$ Since $G$ is a group, we have $x*e = e*x = x.$ So, by a direct compution, we obtain $e = \dfrac{1}{2}-3.$

As it well known, $x*y = 2(x+3)(y+3) - 3.$ By induction on $k,$ one gets $$x^k:=\underset{\text{ $k$ times}}{\underbrace{x*x*\cdots * x}} = 2^{k-1}(x+3)^k - 3.$$ On the other hand, $x^k  =e = \dfrac{1}{2}-3,$ so, we have $2^{k-1}(x+3)^k - 3 = \dfrac{1}{2}-3.$ Hence, $[2(x+3)]^k = 1 \leftrightarrow 2(x+3) = 1$ or $2(x+3) = -1,$ and $k  =2.$ Thus, $x = \dfrac{1}{2}-3 = e$ or $x = -\dfrac{1}{2}-3$ and ord($x$) = 2.

I hope you can give me some suggestions on this solution. Any corrections or constructive criticism on my writing would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't strike me as particularly obvious that $(G, *)$ is a group -- did you use some kind of "transport," or find the identity and inverses by hand?

Comment: First, writing the exponential notation for $*$ is really dangerous as it is impossibile to understand if one means $x*x$ $n$-times or just $x^n$. Moreover I think your induction argument is not right, think it's wrong the $k-1$ exponent to the $2$ coefficient, it should be simply $2$

Comment: I have edited my solution as above. I think that $\underset{\text{ $k$ times}}{\underbrace{x*x*\cdots *x}} = 2^{k-1}(x+3)^k - 3$ is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is easy to see (and shown in the previous comments) that $\tau:G\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}^*$ defined by $\tau(x)=2(x+3)$ is an isomorphism so the torsion elements of $G$ are precisely the counterimages of the torsion elements of $\mathbb{Q}^*$ by $\tau$, id est $1$ and $-1$. So they are $\tau^{-1}(1)=\frac{1}{2}-3$ and $\tau^{-1}(-1)=-\frac{1}{2}-3$

Answer (score 2):

3 is a bit too present in the definition, this can suggest to see what $G$ really is. Take the map $\tau:=\tau_3:G\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}^*$ defined by $\tau(x)=x+3$ and note first that this is a bijection but more interestingly that $\tau(x)\tau(y)=(x+3)(y+3)=\tau((x+3)(y+3)-3)=\tau(x*y)$. This shows that your group is simply a "relabeling" of the group $\mathbb{Q}^*$. Finding torsion elements (the ones of finite order) follows immediately. Hope the explanation was clear.

Comment: I think that $\tau((x + 3)(y+3) - 3)\neq \tau(x*y)$, since $x*y = 2(x+3)(y+3) -3$

Comment: I am really sorry, totally didn't see the $2$ :D however you have $\tau(x*y)=2\tau(x)\tau(y)$. I think this could still help
Try to study $\mathbb{Q}^*$ with the operation given by $x\times y:=2xy$

Comment: You want $\tau(x)=2(x+3)$, then $\tau^{-1}(\tau(x)\cdot \tau(y))=2(x+3)(y+3)-3=x*y$.

Comment: Nice, thanks :) @ThomasAndrews corrected my argument, now it's right and you can continue reading the original answer (with the due modifications)

Comment: @Tancredi  Thank for your help! I have edited my question as above.

Comment: You should have used the $\tau$ given from @ThomasAndrews. I'm going to show you an improvement of your argument later

Comment: I hope to receive your improvements. Thank you very much!

Comment: I wrote an answer to help the reading